# Issue with Deserialization of Enum to string using System.Text.JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

I am currently using .NET 6 and System.Text.Json for serialization. I am having issues where system.text.json does not deserialize the enum to string properly when I return the response using OkObjectResult or ObjectResult

I have used the following on model

```
public class Customer
{
    public string? id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Address { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public CustomerType Type {get; set;}
}
```

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum CustomerType
{
    NEW,
    EXISTING
}
```

Now the API Code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerById(string Id)
    {
        var results = await _customerService.GetData(Id);
        // The results have correct JSON data with enum as string but as soon as I pass this to OkObjectResult, it changes the enum back to int
        return new OkObjectResult(results );
           
    }
```

Service

```
public async Task<Customer> GetData(string Id)
    {
        var results = await _httpClient.SendAsync(Id);  // Get Data
        var jsonResults = await results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{ Converters ={
        new JsonStringEnumConverter()};

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Customer>(jsonResults ,
            options ) ;  // This returns the data correctly
}
```

Now my question why OkObjectResult breaks the code and return the integer instead of enum string value

Comment: You say "The results have correct JSON data with enum as string..." but the `results` are actually a strongly typed `Customer`, meaning they aren't JSON at all: they're a C# object. The CustomerType property on that object is not a string, it's a `CustomerType` enum. So the question is, how is the framework choosing to serialize that C# object you're passing in? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I am not sure if I understand, but did you check the service. The results are coming from service which uses System.Text.JSON and has serializer options of JsonStringEnumConverter

Comment: The service uses System.Text.JSON to _deserialize_ the json results from the http client _into a C# class_ (`Customer`). `GetData` doesn't return JSON: it returns a `Customer`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior So what should I do? Can you help

Comment: I probably can't help much based on the information provided. Sedat's answer should have worked, unless there's some other code somewhere that's overriding that configuration. Maybe check what other converters are configured on your JsonOptions? Make sure you don't have another line of configuration code telling Web API to use the Newtonsoft serializer?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I have checked it everywhere that there is no other configuration

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the contents of the `jsonResults` string?  Also, is there any chance that, in your production code, the property is actually nullable, i.e. `public CustomerType? Type {get; set;}`

Comment: @dbc It is not nullable. The jsonResults are "customer":{"id":"123","type":"NEW"}

So the type here is enum and it returns string

Comment: @LearnAspNet - Wait -- does `jsonResults` equal `{"id":"123","type":"NEW"}` or `{"customer":{"id":"123","type":"NEW"}}`?  Your comment shows some sort of wrapper object (but omits the outer braces and so is technically malformed) which leaves me confused as to the precise contents of jsonResults.

Comment: @dbc it is an example, the whole point is that it returns the type as string instead of a number. I have verified that many times and before this line of code, results are correct with string values

return new OkObjectResult(results);

Comment: @LearnAspNet - honestly, without a [mcve] you will be lucky to get help.  Your `Customer` type serializes correctly as `{"id":"id","Name":null,"Address":null,"Type":"NEW"}` when `System.Text.Json` is called directly, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/K1LDyC.  And Sedat's answer should work even when `JsonStringEnumConverter` is not applied directly.  This leads me to believe you need to recheck your assumptions, and creating a [mcve] will force you to do that,

Comment: That being said, you have the following problems with the JSON in your comment: 1) `"customer":{"id":"123","type":"NEW"}` is malformed because it lacks outer braces.  2) `{"customer":{"id":"123","type":"NEW"}}` has a wrapper object not reflected in you `Customer` data model.  3) `{"id":"123","type":"NEW"}` is camel cased but  in your call `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Customer>(jsonResults, options )` you don't use `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`.  So as shown your ` GetData(string Id)` method should not be returning a correctly populated `Customer`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to introduce the enum converter to ASP.NET in your startup code, like this:

```cs
services.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   var converter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(converter);
});
```

Comment: Still does not work. The response is still a number

Comment: @LearnAspNet In that case, I don't have any more ideas based on what you shared. Serialization should work perfectly with your example.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't appear to work (.Net 8). All enums still serialize as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason can be related to the fact that you are registering multiple Json serialize options: Jsone & NewtonsoftJson at the same time.
Keeping only one may resolve the issue.
[image: JsonStringEnumConverter]